# ADF Tumbling Window Trigger: Dependency trigger not working as expected

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created a tumbling window trigger for my Azure Data Factory Pipeline **Test_Daily** with recurrence as 24 hours. For this pipeline, i have added a dependency trigger lets say **Test_Hourly** (which runs every hour) with offset as 1.00:00:00(1 day).

Test_Daily pipeline is not getting triggered **even though the dependency trigger has run successfully**. For example, if the daily pipeline windowStartTime is 2020-09-20 00:00:00 and Test_Hourly with WindowStartTime 2020-09-21 00:00:00 has run successfully, then the daily pipeline should get triggered. However, this is not the case and Test_Daily gets triggered only when Test_Hourly has completed 2020-09-22 00:00:00(i.e. with 2 day offset).

Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Accept the answer that is helpful in answering the query as it is beneficial to community members

Answer (score 1):

I think it is your setting problem.

- Your **Test_Daily** will start at 2020-09-20 00:00:00 and end at 2020-09-21 00:00:00.
- Your **Test_Hourly** will wait for **Test_Daily** to complete and then delay 1.00:00:00(1 day) to complete at (2020-09-22 00:00:00).
- **Test_Hourly** will Waiting on dependency.

Answer (score 0):

yes, it is behaving as per the design with the applied settings.

Tumbling window trigger starts at window end time (For daily pipeline it is 2020-09-21 00:00:00) and it adds offset (1 day) to it and pipeline actually runs at 2020-09-22 00:00:00.

The same is replicated when I have used hourly and 5minute triggers. In this case, hourly is dependent on 5minute trigger with an offset of 5minutes and the delay of 5min after window time is seen in triggering time of hourly trigger.